# Converting EMF files to bitmaps and getting the right size

Tags: delphi, bitmap

The scenario is that I have a printer EMF file. I'm wanting to overlay some data on it before sending it to the printer. The printer file is 300dpi. It's important to keep the same print quality.

I'm converting the emf file using this code ...

```
  b:=TBitmap.create;
  MyMetaFile.LoadFromFile(emf);
  MyCanvas:= TMetafileCanvas.Create(MyMetaFile, 0);
  try
    Width:=MyMetaFile.Width;
    Height:=MyMetaFile.Height;

    b.width:=width;
    b.height:=height;
    b.Canvas.Draw(0, 0, MyMetaFile);
    b.SaveToFile('c:\emftest.bmp');
```

That kind of works except you only get the top left corner of the emf file. If you look at the properties of the EMF file in windows, it says 2551x3301. But width and height here are set to 613x792. If I override the b.width and b.height with these values it's all ok, but I obviously don't want to do that. The EMF file is 300dpi, the screen dpi is about 100, yet the error is a factor of 4.16. Any idea what is going on here?

Thanks
Terry

Comment: Can you post your emf file somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Thanks to Arnaud for his comments.)

When working with matafiles, only the bitmap data will be rendered when you load the file unless you use the Windows GDI methods to render (or play) the vector content.  I use a 3rd party library (GDI+) to do the work for me.  I also use Graphics32 whenever I work with images.

### GDI+

The author's website doesn't seem to have the source code anymore.  However, I found it [here](http://www.codeforge.com/read/36727/GDIPOBJ.pas__html) by searching for `gdipobj.pas`.  I found it on `code.google.com` as well (included in several projects, [like this one](https://code.google.com/p/ihiewer/source/browse/trunk/components/?r=2)).

### Graphics32

The source for Graphics32 is on SourceForge [here](https://graphics32.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/graphics32/trunk).  The SVN command is:

```
svn co https://graphics32.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/graphics32/trunk graphics32
```

### My Solution

It took a while to figure out how to properly render the Metafile, at the right size, etc.  Here is the function that I use.

```
uses
  GR32, GDIPOBJ, ActiveX;

procedure RenderWMF(var WMF: TMemoryStream; OutputBitmap: TBitmap32; const ScreenResolution: Integer = 96);
var
  gph: TGPGraphics;
  img: TGPImage;
  bmap: TBitmap;
  ms: IStream;
  pLi: PLongint;
  iPos: Int64;
  tmpms: TMemoryStream;
begin
  WMF.Position := 0;
  ms := TStreamAdapter.Create(WMF, soReference);
  try
    pLi := nil;
    ms.Write(WMF.Memory, WMF.Size, pLi);
    bmap := TBitmap.Create;
    try
      ms.Seek(0, soFromBeginning, iPos);
      img := TGPImage.Create(ms);
      try
        bmap.width := Trunc(img.GetWidth / img.GetHorizontalResolution * ScreenResolution + 0.5);
        bmap.height := Trunc(img.GetHeight / img.GetVerticalResolution * ScreenResolution + 0.5);
        gph := TGPGraphics.Create(bmap.Canvas.Handle);
        try
          gph.DrawImage(img, 0, 0, bmap.Width, bmap.Height);
          tmpms := TMemoryStream.Create;
          try
            bmap.SaveToStream(tmpms);
            tmpms.Position := 0;
            OutputBitmap.LoadFromStream(tmpms);
          finally
            tmpms.Free;
          end;
        finally
          gph.Free;
        end;
      finally
        img.Free;
      end;
    finally
      bmap.Free;
    end;
  finally
    ms := nil;
  end;
end;
```

I call it with code like this:

```
var
  bm32: TBitmap32;
  wmf: TMemoryStream;
begin
  bm32 := TBitmap32.Create;
  try
    wmf := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      wmf.LoadFromFile('metafile.emf');
      RenderWMF(wmf, bm32, Screen.PixelsPerInch);
      // Do something with 'bm32'
    finally
      wmf.Free;
    end;
  finally
    bm32.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I know this answer is much broader than `how to properly set the canvas size`.  I hope it is helpful.

Comment: There is also this library: [`IGDI+`](http://www.mitov.com/products/igdi+#features). A link into documentation: [`Enum_IGDIPlus.TGPMetafileType`](http://www.mitov.com/wiki/index.php?title=Enum_IGDIPlus.TGPMetafileType).

Comment: -1 IMHO you recall wrong. TMetaFile can handle any vectorial content. This is a low level GDI format. And using GDI+ as such won't help - drawing won't be anti-aliased, may miss some vectorial commands, and will be slower than plain GDI. If you want true anti-aliaising drawing of metafile using GDI+ you need [to use something like our Open Source unit](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2010/04/02/Antialiased-drawing-from-TMetaFile).

Comment: @James That seems to be closer to what I need, I see the contents are present. But it's taken the 300dpi image and changed it to a 96dpi one and lost a lot of detail in the process. The emf file is a printer file that I'm just wanting to overlay some extra info on before sending it to the printer.

Comment: @Terry - Did you try passing in 300 for the ScreenResolution?  `RenderWMF(wmf, bm32, 300)`

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez - Thanks for helping me remember the real issue -- it wasn't that the `TMetaFile` is inadequate, it is that most people just try to open the metafile without **playing** it, which doesn't render the vectorial content.  I'll revise my answer to be more accurate.

Comment: @James If I change the resolution to 300 it generates a much larger bitmap but with the same resolution image off in the top left corner occupying about 10% of the page.

Comment: @Terry - `DrawImage()` has several overloads that may help.  For instance, `gph.DrawImage(img, 0, 0, bmap.Width, bmap.Height);`.  There are several others as well, but I haven't experimented with any of them.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `StrechDraw` instead of `Draw` here, in order to scale the content to the expected bitmap size.

For instance:

```
function MetafileToBitmap(Source: TMetafile; ScaleX,ScaleY: integer): TBitmap;
var R: TRect;
begin
  result := nil;
  if Source=nil then // self=nil is OK below
    Exit;
  R.Left := 0;
  R.Right := (Source.Width*ScaleX)div 100;
  R.Top := 0;
  R.Bottom := (Source.Height*ScaleY)div 100;
  result := TBitmap.Create;
  result.Width := R.Right;
  result.Height := R.Bottom;
  Dec(R.Right);  // Metafile rect includes right and bottom coords
  Dec(R.Bottom);
  PlayEnhMetaFile(Result.Canvas.Handle,Source.Handle,R);
end;
```

If you want anti-aliased drawing using GDI+, you will need to enumerate the metafile content then render it with [our Open Source SynGdiPlus unit](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2010/04/02/Antialiased-drawing-from-TMetaFile):

```
function LoadFrom(const MetaFile: TMetaFile): TBitmap;
```

Comment: Ok, I've installed the code and do this and it does give a file of the right size. But now all the text is gone, it's just a white sheet with a couple of border lines. My emf file is just a couple of lines of text + some framing.

Comment: I edited my answer. Just use PlayEnhMetaFile() API, for GDI rendering. Or use `function LoadFrom(const MetaFile: TMetaFile): TBitmap;` function available in SynGdiPlus. Ensure you got the latest version from [our source code repository](http://synopse.info/fossil/finfo?name=SynGdiPlus.pas).

Comment: I'll look at `SynGdiPlus`.  I prefer a 3rd party library that is actively maintained...

Comment: @JamesL. What do you call "actively maintained"? Our Open Source units are one of the most active code in the Delphi world. And IMHO no other Delphi GDI+ is able to render plain EMF content with anti-aliaising. The code in your answer won't be able to draw the content with anti-aliaising, whereas our unit is able of that. This was the main point of my answer.